# Divisibility represented by Boolean logic

Tags: elementary-number-theory, predicate-logic, boolean-algebra, satisfiability

Some context: I was thinking about the feasibility of using SAT solvers to prove primality, especially of Mersenne primes, by showing that there exists no Boolean sequence $d_1,d_2, ..., d_{b'}$ that can represent a divisor of the prime (i.e. UNSAT).

Given a Boolean list $d_1,d_2, ..., d_{b'}$, where $d$ is the base-2 representation of a base-10 positive integers $D$, does there exist a Boolean predicate that evaluates to True if and only if $2^b-1 \equiv 0 ($mod D)$?

(Assume $1 < D < N$, and hence, $b' < b$. Also assume $b$ is prime.)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Isn't it just the case that *any* boolean-valued function of $b+b'$ boolean variables can be represented using Boolean algebra operations?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a circuit which performs a *modular reduction* as explained in [this lecture note](https://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9783642546488-c2.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-1452412-p176644198) (chapter 2.6.4 on page 32). The modular reduction computes the remainder of the division $N/D$. Use a digital comparator circuit to check for zero remainder. When the remainder vanishes to zero, the predicate becomes true.

From the cited lecture note:
[image]

Note that this might not fully answer your question as it assumes $D$ to be a constant rather than a variable.

Comment: Close. However, can this be directly evaluated with Boolean logic? I want to implement the predicate directly (i.e. a sequence of logical operations). This is an interesting idea, though.

Comment: Yes. An alternative would be to calculate the remainder $R$ as $R = N - D * (N/D)$. But that would require a divider, a subtractor and a multiplier.

Comment: Subtraction and multiplication of Boolean arrays can be done as if it was in base-2. (subtraction is trivial XOR and NAND for carrying, multiplication can be expanded into addition, i.e. XOR and AND) This question concerns division.

Comment: Divider circuits are actually described in the above-mentioned book [Basic Arithmetic Circuits](https://rd.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-54649-5_2). My point ist that modular reduction is less complex than the classic remainder calculation.